# How to mux Vorbis audio and VP8 video into WebM format with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, vorbis

I have a Vorbis audio and VP8 encoded video, and would like to mux them into WebM format.

How do I mux them with FFmpeg, and also set the display aspect ratio to 16:9?

I'm using Windows 7 with the latest FFmpeg build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic remuxing example:

```
ffmpeg -i video -i audio -c copy -aspect 16:9 output.webm
```

- `-c copy` will enable [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode and therefore will avoid re-encoding.
- Because `-aspect` was used with `-c copy`, the aspect ratio will be stored at the container level; not in the video stream. I'm not sure if WebM supports this, or if players will pay attention to it, but I will assume it does.